# Unable to connect to Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition using JDBC

Tags: database, oracle11g

As I am using **SQL Plus(Oracle 11g Enterprise edition)** and I can't have access to the express edition so I need to connect to the enterprise ed. only. So what should be the **SID name for enterprise edition 11g**, which is XE for the express edition?

Comment: You need to ask a person who set up database on that enterprise edition.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The SID name will be the only change that I need to make in url, right? Like in this case, after the port number I will be updating the change "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:??"